# Excel to PDF Conversion

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have an excel workbook with many sheets. The data needs to be converted to PDF.

Now the catch is that there are a few images that have to be present in the header and footer of the PDF. Also the page number needs to be printed.

Can u suggest the best approach to handle this. I work on VBA. Can anyone tell if this can be achieved using Excel - VBA?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, I have solved my problem with this.. as you haven't posted any specific details... you need to figure out how to use this code...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wksAllSheets As Variant ' define a worksheet object arrray
    Dim wksSheet1 As Worksheet  ' a dummy variable
    Dim strFilename As String   ' file name
    Dim strFilepath As String   ' file path, default is the current working dir

    ' file destination folder name...
    strFilepath = "C:\Reports" 

    ' check if folder exist or not, if doesn't then creates it otherwise ignore it
    If Len(Dir(strFilepath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
       MkDir strFilepath
   End If

    strFilepath = strFilepath & "\"

    ' Initialize variables
    wksAllSheets = Array("Strategy", "Summary", "Trades", "TradeAnalysis") '' array of sheetName i want to save as pdf 
    strFilename  = "outputFileName.pdf"





    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''  Here I am setting the page layout for each sheet, use if you need '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Set wksSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Strategy")
    ' change the page setup Attributes of 'Strategy' sheet object
    With wksSheet1.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = xlPaperFanfoldLegalGerman
    .Zoom = 85
    .TopMargin = 0
    .BottomMargin = 0
    .RightMargin = 0
    .LeftMargin = 0
    .HeaderMargin = 0
    .FooterMargin = 0
    End With

    ' change the page setup Attributes of 'Summary' sheet object
     Set wksSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
    With wksSheet1.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
    .Zoom = 90
    .TopMargin = 0.25
    .BottomMargin = 0.25
    .RightMargin = 0.25
    .LeftMargin = 0.25
    .HeaderMargin = 0.25
    .FooterMargin = 0.25
    End With

    ' change the page setup Attributes of 'Trades' sheet object
    Set wksSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trades")
    With wksSheet1.PageSetup
    .CenterHeader = "Trades"
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PrintArea = "$B$2:$U$321"   ' pass it as a parameter
    .Zoom = 100
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
    .PrintTitleRows = wksSheet1.Rows(2).Address
    End With

    ' change the page setup Attributes of 'TradeAnalysis' sheet object
     Set wksSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TradeAnalysis")
    With wksSheet1.PageSetup
    .CenterHeader = "TradeAnalysis"
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .LeftMargin = 0.25
    .RightMargin = 0.25
    .Zoom = 100
    End With

   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''



    'Save all the sheet in the array as one single PDF file
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wksAllSheets).Select
    wksSheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat _
              Type:=xlTypePDF, _
              Filename:=strFilepath & strFilename, _
              Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
              IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
              IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
              OpenAfterPublish:=True
    'update the wksSheet1 object in with the next entry from wksAllSheets array of object
    wksSheet1.Select


End Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

and here is a [reference](https://powerspreadsheets.com/save-excel-file-pdf-vba/)