# How to generate pdf from each row of a excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have an excel sheet with multiple rows containing employee salary breakdown(like, basic, medical, conveyance etc), I want to create a button in excel using macro that will generate multiple pdf for multiple rows.Is that possible? If so, please help me with sharing some helpful links

Comment: Have you checked for other questions on here about excel to pdf? there are many that may help.

Comment: Try looking at this one, you will have to edit the code to suit... : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46400030/4961700